# Where to find the front worn bags/pouches that ESF instructors wear

Tags: backpacks, skiing

I just got back from some time skiing, during which I wore a backpack to carry my off piste gear and water, etc. I saw many of the ESF (École du Ski Français) instructors wearing front mounted pouches rather than backpacks, and thought they looked like a really good idea for days when you don't have much gear and want easy access/a hassle free time on chair lifts.

I've tried to find these things for a while now and got absolutely nowhere; I can't even find a picture of one being worn to show what I mean. Does anyone have any idea what these are called and where I might get one (or take a look to decide if it's worth it)? They had three straps, one going over a shoulder and two around the body, were of smallish size and were black. I'm afraid that's really all I've got to go off.

Comment: This might be what you are talking about.  Search on radio harness.  http://raggedmountain.com/ski-18/radio-pack

Comment: Looks pretty good cheers! I remember them being a bit larger but hopefully can dig something up with this to google.

Comment: You may also want to search "radio chest rig". This will give you a lot of military stuff, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google

```
     waist packs for travel
```

This isn't quite what you are looking for, but may be functional enough for your purpose.  Padded ones are often used by photographers.  In use, you commonly have them on your bum for walking, and slide around to the front for access.

As another option, check out forester's vests.  These are much like a photographer's vest, but with larger pockets.  They usually come in eye searingly bright colours.  Most forestry supply and safety supply stores.

When I was a volunteer ski patrol we had waist packs.  The pros had a larger pack, about a 25 liter day pack.  I never noticed how they rode the chairlift with them.

Comment: Cheers pal, lots to go off.